# Apache fop-0.95 error on FopFactory.newInstance() command

Tags: java, apache, apache-fop

```
I am using Apache fop-0.95 to build pdf files from a JSP web application on IBM iSeries V5R4 using Websphere 6.0.  Everything works perfect in my development using Websphere Development Studio client.  When I put the application on the server, I get an error at this line.

    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();

The error is:

    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: javax/imageio/ImageIO

Does anyone know how I can fix this error?

All of the fop class files are part of the EAR file.  The files were installed to the projects \WEB-INF\lib directory.  I have added the fop jar files to the classpath, using the admin console. 

I am running IBM WebSphere Application Server - Express, 6.0.2.9
```

Build Number: cf90614.22 on IBM iSeries V5R4

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that lies lower than on the Java classpath. Some libraries may be missing. Maybe PASE (http://www-03.ibm.com/servers/enable/site/porting/iseries/pase/overview.html) is missing since you're mentioning iSeries. See also:
http://ecommunity.groupintelligence.com/websphere/forums/archive/index.php/t-1932.html